# How to add border to <a-text> in A-Frame?

Tags: css, aframe

I need to add border to  in A-frame.
A-text does't have border attibute. 
https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/primitives/a-text.html
How I can do it?

Comment: why don't you include the entire `a-frame` in a `div` and add the border to the `div` element? Can you please provide the code in order to proper see what you want

Answer (score 1):

First of all its not a question about css, because all of `a-frame`'s content is rendered in a canvas by the three.js -> webGL engine, where css styling won't apply.

There is a [border component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-border-component), but I'm not sure if its being updated.

How about making a .png with a border and transparent middle, and set it as the text child like this:

```
 <a-text>
   <a-entity material="src:border.png"></a-entity>
 </a-text>
```

it may seem like a workaround, but its similar to what one of the creators proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45290438/aframe-io-add-border-to-a-curvedimage-on-mouseover-using).

---

You could also create a component making a border out of four `<a-plane>`'s.